# How do I smooth all the JavaScript transitions?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-transitions, smoothing

So, I made some interaction that are triggered every click, I could've used switch too but I wanted to make it more readable.
All these transitions have something in common and that is they finish in an instant, so I tried to use css `* { transition: all 0.5s; }` and even `body { 
transition: all 0.5s; }` but the transitions don't seem to smooth. Not even the background change is not smooth. And every time the innerHTML changes it happens instantly and I am trying not to mess myself fading in span after span. So the question is, how do I make all transitions smooth? Thanks in advance :D

```
  var text = 0;

function changeText() {
  text += 1;
  if (text === 0) {
document.getElementById('secHeader').innerHTML = "Click anywhere to begin.";
}
else if (text === 1) {
document.getElementById('secHeader').innerHTML = "Are you ready?";
}
else if (text === 2) {
document.getElementById('secHeader').innerHTML = "Let's begin then...";
}
else if (text === 3) {
document.getElementById('secHeader').innerHTML = "You're about to experience a journey you'll never forget.";
}
else if (text === 4) {
document.getElementById('ImageBox').style.display = "none";
document.body.style.background = "black";
}
else if (text === 5) {
document.getElementById('thHeader').style.display = "block";
}
else if (text === 6) {
document.getElementById('thHeader').innerHTML = "You must be very curious then..."
}
else if (text === 7) {
document.getElementById('thHeader').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById('ftHeader').style.display = "block";
}
else if (text === 8) {
document.getElementById('ftHeader').innerHTML = "We can show you something..."
}
else if (text === 9) {
document.getElementById('ftHeader').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById('ffHeader').style.display = "block";
}
else if (text === 10) {
  document.getElementById('ffHeader').innerHTML = "Let's see..."
}
else if (text === 11) {
document.getElementById('ffHeader').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, 
#203a43, #2c5364)";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'display: none' and then 'block' the transition property won't work. The element should be in the DOM, and 'display: none' deletes element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There are [some CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) which can being affected by transition's effect.